# Azure Merge Multiple Subscriptions

Tags: azure

If I use multiple subscriptions to limit access and provisioning by users and later decide I don't need to or find a better method to manage this in Azure can I merge the subscriptions later on without losing all of the Azure resources or copying the VM's over?

Comment: I think some of the resources can move between subscriptions but others cannot.  For instance, a storage account cannot move but cloud services can.

Comment: Currently you can do it by contacting support. However please keep in mind that it is all-or-none kind of a deal. Support will move all of your assets from one subscription to another. You can't say which assets to move and not move. Furthermore, there are certain kind of assets which you can't move. I don't remember them from the top of my head but when you open a support ticket, they will let you know.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I read an article on moving VHD's as a blob, and not being able to move storage acct makes sense.  Instead of using different subscriptions what is a better way to segregate multiple AZ environments like dev/test/prod under a single account?

Answer (score 1):

@acruns, to answer your follow-up question "what is a better way to segregate multiple AZ environments like dev/test/prod under a single account?"... my suggestions would be to use Deployment Slots.

Note that all deployment slots for a specific website do share the same Web Hosting Plan, while existing in the same VM instance that hosts the Prod slot.

Source: Azure 70-532 Study Guide

For more info:

- Staging Slots: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/
- Web Hosting Plans: https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/04/04/introducing-web-hosting-plans-for-azure-web-sites/

Hope that helps! :-)